# How to parse the argument in the following C++ code?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been unable to parse the executable with the build of the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    if(argc==3)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[1],"-i")==0)
        {
            string DueEXE, DueVER;
            DueEXE = DueVER = "";
            DueEXE += argv[2];
            cout << endl << DueEXE;
            DueVER += "\"" + DueEXE + "\" -ver > \"C:\\\\DueVER\"";
            cout << endl << DueVER << endl << endl;
            system(DueVER.c_str());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Prerequisites:**
 ***1.** DueEXE* holds the file location to an *.exe that prints (in console) its version when used with -ver or --ver.
**2.** I use Windows XP SP3.
**3.** I use Code::Blocks with MinGW32, if that matters.
**Problem encountered:**
When I execute my build using **cmd** as follows-
**1.** build.exe -i "D:\OA 2\Due.exe" 
**2.** build.exe -i "D:/OA 2/Due.exe", 
the result is something like-

```
D:/OA 2/Due.exe
D:/OA 2/Due.exe -ver > "C:\DueVER"

'D:/OA' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I know that I have to parse the 3<sup>rd</sup> argument with quotes.
Additionally, the result should be like-

```
"D:/OA 2/Due.exe"
"D:/OA 2/Due.exe" -ver > "C:\DueVER"
```

The entire *Due.exe* file location must be covered with quotes, but that doesn't happen.
What's going wrong in the code?

Comment: I suspect the problem might be having four backslashes for `\"C:\\\\DueVER\"` when I *think* you  only need 2: `\"C:\\DueVER\"`. The other part (though over-complex) seems to work for me (but I'm on Linux so....).

Comment: @Galik
I used double backslashes. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh!
I forgot to call the `system()` function with the variable covered in quotes.
Replacing `system(DueVER.c_str())` with `system(("\""+DueVER+"\"").c_str())` did my work.